# How can I get the collectionView's current section number in real time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, self.collectionView.contentOffset.y)];
    NSLog(@"sectionNumber===%ld",path.section);

// 菜单button滚动到相应的位置
   [self.menuButtonView scrollToButtonWithButtonNumber:path.section];
}
```

The console shows "sectionNumber===0" all the time but actually it should be 1 to 10. I don't know where I made mistakes,what's more,I had set the collectionView's delegate.
It waste my 3 hours already,I really need some help.

Comment: 1) `contentOffset` is already a `CGPoint`, so you can pass it to `indexPathForItemAtPoint` directly.  2) Have you verified that there is actually an item at the `contentOffset`?  Perhaps it's a point in the margin.

Comment: Are you sure you have multiple section or you are looking for path.row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After half of a day's hard try,I solved this problem at last.The key to solve this problem is CollectionView's two delegate function:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplaySupplementaryView:(UICollectionReusableView *)view forElementKind:(NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView:(nonnull UICollectionReusableView *)view forElementOfKind:(nonnull NSString *)elementKind atIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

With these two delegate function,you can get current section correctly.

Answer (score 1):

in scrollViewDidScroll, you could get all index path of visible cells of your collection view, then get the middle index path and get it's section.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.mainImageCollection indexPathsForVisibleItems];
    NSIndexPath *middleIndexPath = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:([indexPaths count]/2)];//you must check if indexPaths >=2 or <2
    NSLog(@"indexPath : %d at Section :%d",middleIndexPath.item,middleIndexPath.section);
}
```

I hope this Help !

Comment: cloud you please explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   NSIndexPath *centerCellIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[self.view convertPoint:[self.view center] toView:self.collectionView]];
   NSLog(@"Index:%ld",(long)centerCellIndexPath.row);     
}
```